# Recursive generator in Pythonic way?

Tags: python, functional-programming

Below is a generator that can create all combinations made of one character from a number of strings:

```
('ab', 'cd', 'ef') => 'ace', 'acf', 'ade', 'adf', 'bce', 'bcf', 'bde', 'bdf'.
```

However, I wonder if this can be done in a more Pythonic.

```
# Example input data
t = ('ab', 'cd', 'ef')

# Recursive generator
def comb(t):
    if t:
        for c in t[0]:
            for s in comb(t[1:]):
                yield c + s 
    else:
        yield ''

# Test of generator
for r in comb(t):
    print(r)
```

Comment: Seems quite pythonic to me. What part is wrong in your eyes?

Comment: The double `for` loop appears clumsy, and I wonder whether the `if t:` part can somehow be removed.  I have started digging into Python functional programming features, so I consider if there could be some smarter way.

Comment: You could drop the "if/else" and just propagate the exception when you reach t[0] and t==None. Catching that exception is more Pythonic than type checking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lis = ('ab', 'cd', 'ef')
for p in product(*lis):
    print "".join(p)
...     
ace
acf
ade
adf
bce
bcf
bde
bdf
```